# Error:Cannot get property 'args' on null object when build on android studio

Tags: android, react-native, args

I am doing an react native project. When I open the project on Android Studio. The following error is shown.

```
Error:Cannot get property 'args' on null object
```

I have checked setting gradle. It is just like bellow:

```
rootProject.name = 'my_app_name'
include ':app'
```

I also wonder what is 'args' in this statement.

Comment: Do you have some lib. to link that you are forgetting?

Comment: I didn't see any lib in this setting.gradle @Codesingh

Comment: did you integrate any external lib in your application..?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this error.My solution is find 'your project root path'/node_modules/react-native-config/android/dotenv.gradle 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiUI3.jpg)

```html
def getCurrentFlavor() {
Gradle gradle = getGradle()
String tskReqStr = gradle.getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString()

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(assemble|generate|install)(.*?)(Debug|Release)")
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tskReqStr)

if( matcher.find() ) {
String variant = matcher.group(2) + matcher.group(3)
return variant.toLowerCase()
} else {
return "";
}
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYqwk.png)

I hope it help you!

Comment: avoid attaching screenshoots of code. just post the code itself